# Unity Client and Multiplayer Networking/Architecture

Tags: unity, architecture, multiplayer, client-server

My background is in Enterprise and SaaS web infrastructure.  Zero information about games and how their networking works.  I only know about the world of browsers and RESTful APIs.

I'm planning on using Unity for the client FYI.

**Authentication and Authorization**

I'm planning to use Unity and Firebase.  Seems like this is fairly standard HTTP connections during the auth faze.  Nothing surprising here unless there is something I missed.

The client authenticates against a service, Firebase in this case.  And then all future calls after authentication are made using the returned credentials.

**Gameplay and Player State**

This part confuses me.  I assume shooters use a UDP type protocol or some proprietary protocol on top of UDP. But can a game use a REST API and HTTP or TCP connections to send client updates?

Clients would then poll the game server or have a long running connection open to request updates.  For example the Auction House in WoW.  Is there a long lived TCP connection open between the client and the server updating the auction house data every X seconds?

Then when a player submits a purchase order that same long lived TCP connection is used to update the game server state?

Or is it all literally a REST API like a SaaS app would use?  Is my experience with browsers and Single Page Apps in an Enterprise environment applicable to a WoW auction house type situation?

Thank you,
Any tips or feedback is helpful at this point.

Comment: How would you implement an auction house in a RESTful way? Where do you run into difficulty? If you don't see any specific problem, then just go ahead and implement it like that. If you encounter a specific problem, then try editing your question to describe the specific problem you've encountered, and ask for strategies to solve it.

Comment: That's fair, will just prioritize speed instead of learning something new preemptively. Thanks!